# I do not have the relieving letter or Experience letter from my first company in Saudi Arabia

Tags: relieving-letter

I have worked 2 years on contract basis in one of the company in Saudi Arabia between 17-Dec-2011 to 17-Dec-2013. However, I have not asked my company to provide the relieving letter or experience letter which shows that I worked with them between the dates I mentioned above. However, I do have the offer letter which says the my date of joining will start from the next day when I land Saudi Arabia (Which falls 17-Dec-2011) as I boarded the flight on 16-Dec-2011 and at the time of my exit company has given me the exit visa, final clearance (e.i., Final Settlement copy) and airport immigration dates which proves that I went to Saudi for 2 years.

Now, I joined one of the MNC in Bangalore and the company HR is asking the relieving letter. However, I have contacted the HR team in Saudi to provide the scan copy of relieving letter but I have not received any response yet.

Please advise what should I do now.

Thanks,
Shivakumar

Comment: What did your new employer say when you told them what you've written here?

Answer (score 5):

A relieving letter is a purely Indian thing which may be completely unknown in Saudi Arabia.

You will have better success if you ask for a document that has your name and start and end date of employment. Those documents are called different names around the world, but are pretty universal because every country needs them one way or another.

Contact your former employer again and ask about the process, explain what a relieving letter is and if they cannot write one for you, ask for a proof of employment instead.

If they don't answer your email, call them.

Don't forget to keep your MNC updated on the progress.